# Matlab: command to get counts of elements in a list

Tags: matlab, count

I need the counts of each element in the list. Is there some ready command for this?

```
>> [1 1 5 5 10 12 12 2 2 2]

ans =

     1     1     5     5    10    12    12    2    2    2
```

**Goal:** getting counts like this

```
>> [1, 2; 5, 2; 10, 1; 12, 2]

ans =

     1     2
     2     3
     5     2
    10     1
    12     2
```

Comment: `OUT = [unique(IN)' histc(IN,unique(IN))']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the formatting of the result is important to you, but the following link might come in handy. [How can I count the occurrences of each element in a vector in MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96504)

It's an answer to a similar question on the MathWorks website by their support team. They say there is no single function for it, but they provide 3 options.